# edit the EF5 auto generated connection string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created an entity data model which auto generated a connection string for me ! I was using IIS express and everything was just fine.

```
<add name="mvcDemoConString" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.EmpoyeeDataModel.csdl|res://*/Models.EmpoyeeDataModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.EmpoyeeDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=mvcDemo;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

till I changed the web settings to host it on local IIS. then I got this error message (Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'). 
I tried to add another user in my connection string but it didn't work , it is still using the previous user
 changed connectionstring ;

```
<add name="mvcDemoConString" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.EmpoyeeDataModel.csdl|res://*/Models.EmpoyeeDataModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.EmpoyeeDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=mvcDemo;User ID=Web;Password=pa;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection string has both `integrated security=True;` and a specific user id and password.  The specification of `true` for Integrated Security is what is causing the APP POOL id to still be used.

Try removing: `integrated security=True;`

Comment: You're very welcome.  Please mark my answer as the Accepted Answer when you get a chance -- you'll get two reputation point yourself by doing so!